# .addClass() not working inside for() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**UPDATE - FINAL SOLUTION**

Thank you to EVERYONE who has helped me with this problem. **Special thanks must go to @Pranav for all of their help through email**. All of your answers seemed to have worked in JSFiddle yet I could not replicate it on my local server.

My problem was that my js file was firing before PHP had finished adding elements and classes dynamically. I was able to fix this (without using an event handler) with calling:

```
( function() {
    jQuery(window).load( function($) {

// Add stuff

});
})(jQuery);
```

This seems to wait until PHP has done its thang and then fire. I can see the changes happen in the DevTools panel.

I also didn't realise that Wordpress really doesn't seem to like $ and would rather have jQuery, so had to create `$ = jQuery` variable to counter this.

Once again, thank you all. I have only just started learning jQuery and Javascript and this has been a great lesson to learn.

---

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am trying to add classes to a select boxes options depending on the classes they have been given by WooCommerce. (The reason for this is that I gave up trying to point to the 'disabled' property I couldn't get working.)

For some reason, the code I am using isn't adding any classes.

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    // Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
    $selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
    $listclass='turnintoselect';  // class to identify ULs
    $boxclass='dropcontainer';   // parent element
    $triggeron='activetrigger';   // class for the active trigger link
    $triggeroff='trigger';   // class for the inactive trigger link
    $dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
    $dropdownopen='dropdownvisible'; // open dropdown

    $i=0;
    $count=0;
    $sels=$('select');
    $opts=$('option');
    $trigger=('<a href="#"></a>');
    function $switchTriggerClass (){
        $($trigger).toggleClass($triggeron).toggleClass($triggeroff);
    }

    for($i; $i<$opts.length; $i++){
        if($($opts).hasClass('enabled')){
            $(this).addClass('woo');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('foo');
        }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="size">Size</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
            <a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Michael

**EDIT**
Hi all,

I have tried all of these methods and the result is 'foo' being outputted to all option elements. I have also tried these methods on my navigation menu and the li elements are responding how I would expect this code to run.

My only conclusion has to be that Javascript/jQuery is not seeing the class 'enabled' even though it is definitely attached.

Could it be that the script is running before PHP has completed it processing? This is a dynamically loaded select box.

Cheers

Comment: `if($($opts[$i]).hasClass('enabled'))`

Comment: also `this` context is which this?

Comment: Note that the dollar sign is used to mark variables as jQuery Object.
If only jQuery Objects are prefixed by a dollar sign you immedeatly know if its a jQuery Object or something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside for loop `this` not refers to the element it may be `window` object or something else. Yo can resolve the problem using [`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) method.

```
for(; $i < $opts.length; $i++){
    // cache the element reference
    var $item = $opts.eq($i);
    // or $($opts[$i])

    if($item .hasClass('enabled')){
        $item .addClass('woo');
    }
    else {
        $item .addClass('foo');
    }
}
```

```js
var $opts = $('option');

for (var $i = 0; $i < $opts.length; $i++) {
  // cache the element reference
  var $item = $opts.eq($i);
  // or $($opts[$i])

  if ($item.hasClass('enabled')) {
    $item.addClass('woo');
  } else {
    $item.addClass('foo');
  }
}
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red
}

.woo {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
```

Or using [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method instead of for loop

```
$opts.each(function(){
    // cache the element reference
    $item = $(this);

    if($item .hasClass('enabled')){
        $item .addClass('woo');
    }
    else {
        $item .addClass('foo');
    }
});
```

```js
var $opts = $('option');


$opts.each(function() {
  // cache the element reference
  $item = $(this);

  if ($item.hasClass('enabled')) {
    $item.addClass('woo');
  } else {
    $item.addClass('foo');
  }
});
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red
}

.woo {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
```

---

Even you can do it in 2 lines using [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) and [`not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/) methods.

```
// filter all elements with the class and add the class
$opts.filter('.enabled').addClass('woo');      

// filter all elements which doesn't have the class and add the class
$opts.not('.enabled').addClass('foo');
```

```js
var $opts = $('option');

// filter all elements with the class and add the class
$opts.filter('.enabled').addClass('woo');

// filter all elements which doesn't have the class and add the class
$opts.not('.enabled').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red
}

.woo {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
```

The same with a single line using [`end()`](https://api.jquery.com/end) method.

```
$opts
   .filter('.enabled').addClass('woo')
   // back to the previous element object
   .end()
   .not('.enabled').addClass('foo');
```

```js
var $opts = $('option');

// filter all elements with the class and add the class
$opts.filter('.enabled').addClass('woo')
  .end()
  .not('.enabled').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  color: red
}

.woo {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I have tried all of your methods and the ones below, and all the code is outputting is 'foo'. I am assuming that, for some reason, Javascript/jQuery isn't seeing the class 'enabled'. I have run the same codes on my navigation menu and the li elements are responding as expected for the option menu.

Comment: @user3436334 : can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet or in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I can't, it is working in jsfiddle. Could this be due to the script firing before the php has completed?

Comment: @user3436334 : there is `jQuery(document).ready( function($) {....})` so it would run only after ppage elements are loaded

Comment: @user3436334 :  if the class is adding dynamically later .... then do this after the process is completed

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but how would I go about doing this? I have looked around online and cannot find anything regarding this particular problem.

Comment: @user3436334 can you share the live page link or the code?

Comment: I'm developing it locally. I can copy the whole DOM output if you like.

Comment: @user3436334 : mail it to me : pranavcbalan@gmail.com .. let me check :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code block from

```
for($i; $i<$opts.length; $i++){
        if($($opts).hasClass('enabled')){
            $(this).addClass('woo');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('foo');
        }
    }
```

To

```
$opts.each(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('enabled'))
    {
        $(this).addClass('woo');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).addClass('foo');
    }
})
```

---

Another way of doing is :

```
$('option.enabled').addClass('woo');      
$opts.not('.enabled').addClass('foo');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an alternative then you can use `foreach`

```
$opts.each(function(){
        if(($(this)).hasClass('enabled')){
            $(this).addClass('woo');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('foo');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach instead.

```
$sels.find('option').each(function() {
 if($(this).hasClass('enabled')) {
  $(this).addClass('woo');
 } else {
  $(this).addClass('foo');
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In side for loop `this` doesn't give you the current element in loop. you need to use `$($opt[$i]).hasClass()` inorder to access your options in select box.

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {

    // Classes for the link and the visible dropdown
    $selectclass='turnintodropdown';  // class to identify selects
    $listclass='turnintoselect';  // class to identify ULs
    $boxclass='dropcontainer';   // parent element
    $triggeron='activetrigger';   // class for the active trigger link
    $triggeroff='trigger';   // class for the inactive trigger link
    $dropdownclosed='dropdownhidden'; // closed dropdown
    $dropdownopen='dropdownvisible'; // open dropdown

    $i=0;
    $count=0;
    $sels=$('select');
    $opts=$('option');
    $trigger=('<a href="#"></a>');
    function $switchTriggerClass (){
        $($trigger).toggleClass($triggeron).toggleClass($triggeroff);
    }

    
    for($i; $i < $opts.length; $i++){
    
    if($($opts[$i]).hasClass('enabled')){
         $($opts[$i]).addClass('woo');
    }
    else {
        $($opts[$i]).addClass('foo');
    }
}
    

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            <label for="size">Size</label>
        </td>
        <td class="value">
            <select id="size" class="turnintodropdown" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size" data-show_option_none="yes">
            <option value="">- -</option>
            <option value="10" class="attached enabled">10</option>
            <option value="20" class="attached enabled">20</option>
            <option value="30" class="attached enabled">30</option>
            <option value="40" class="attached enabled">40</option>
            <option value="50" class="attached" disabled="">50</option>
            <option value="60" class="attached" disabled="">60</option>
            </select>
            <a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: hidden;"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```